Unable to generate graphics in background (without displaying UI)
I am trying to generate syncfusion charts in the background of a screen opening and thus be able to save them in PNG.
Each chart is in a UserControl with a custom legend (not the synfusion one). So I have to generate this UserControl with the chart (SfCharts) inside and its associated legend and then save it in PNG.
I used these instructions in particular:
private void GenerateGraphImage(object graphiqueBar, GraphiqueSynthese graphique)
{
    // binded property containing with some chart's datas
    GraphiqueSyntheseAAfficher = graphique;

    // try to force render user control
    if (graphiqueBar is UserControl userControl)
    {             
        userControl.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        userControl.Arrange(new Rect(userControl.DesiredSize));
        userControl.UpdateLayout();

        // get image
        var image = ScreenshotHelper.GetImage(userControl);

        // save as png
        SaveImage(image, graphique.GraphiqueName);
    }
}

public static RenderTargetBitmap GetImage(UserControl view)
{
    Size size = new Size(view.ActualWidth, view.ActualHeight);
    if (size.IsEmpty)
        return null;

    RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(view), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
        context.Close();
    }

    result.Render(drawingvisual);
    return result;
}

I can see the UserControl built in memory (by hovering the mouse over the "userControl" variable) after UpdateLayout(), it has a size (ActualWidth and ActualHeight are not 0), the control that builds the legend is correctly built (with the bound properties). On the other hand, the chart is always empty: no data or drawing (bar or curve) appears...

I can't figure out why?
For additional information:

I tried to use the Dispatcher in different priorities (Render in particular) in BeginInvoke. It doesn't change anything...
The legend is built correctly but not the graph which is really surprising. In both cases, I bind to a GraphiqueSyntheseAAfficher property (in the view model), which is an object that contains a set of properties that are bound to the view. For the legend, it's good but the graph is always empty in the image saved in png.

Do you have a solution or an idea of ​​this problem?
An example of the result :


The "chart" should be rendering in the user control (along with the custom legend) regardless of what happens after that (visuals and saving). I see no evidence the chart was rendered in the first place.

Many thanks to @GerrySchmitz for putting me on the path to the solution. Indeed, I had to wait for the chart to render the graphic element before saving as a PNG. THANKS !

Great news! You're welcome.

If someone looking for the solution.
You need to wait the chart rendered its elements (like a bar).
I added a Thread.Sleep(1000) after the forced rendered and before to save the visual as png. And it work !
 chart.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
 chart.Arrange(new Rect(userControl.DesiredSize));
 Thread.Sleep(900);
 // and save as png

Many thanks to Gerry in comments !
